# @SpringBootTest can't not find Jpa Repository with @Autowired

Tags: jpa

I was testing JpaRepository with @SpringBootTest. but somehow it can not find jpa repository bean. I'm using basic spring boot initialze setup with spring boot 2.2.5. Do I need extra configuration for this issue?

```
@SpringBootTest
class BlockRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private BlockRepository blockRepository;
}
```

```
public interface BlockRepository extends JpaRepository<Block, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the question?